# SQL query to get records from same day

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I wish to find all records of the current day.
I have a field `Date` of type DATE.

If I use

```
WHERE `Date` = '2011-04-07'
```

it works

but if I use:

```
WHERE  `Date`='CURDATE()'
```

or

```
WHERE  `Date`='NOW()'
```

it does not return any results (when there actually are some).

How do I get the current date in the right format to use it in my SQL query?

I am using MySQL
And the date was originally entered in the database using NOW().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE `Date`=CURDATE()
```

The quotes (') are used to wrap up a string (text).

Edit: I can see now that you say the value was stored with `NOW()` : it probably includes a time element too.  Will update answer imminently..

This will compare the date part of the Date field to today's date:

```
WHERE DATE(`Date`)=CURDATE()
```