# All posts from same day only django

Tags: python, django, date

I currently have:

```
@classmethod
def get_past_week(self):
    start_date = datetime.now().date()
    end_date = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(weeks=1)
    return MyModel.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(end_date, start_date)).aggregate(Sum('off_hours'))
```

which simply pulls all posts from the current date minus 7 days

I want to pull posts from within the same day factoring in the time at the moment. Thus if the time is 15:00 GMT now, I want all posts from 14:59:49 GMT back to 00:00:01 GMT of the same day. How can I do something like that?

I've tried something like (not work

```
def get_today_hours(self):
    start_time = datetime.now().time()
    end_time = datetime.now().time() - timedelta(hours=datetime.today().hour, minutes=0, seconds=0)
    return MyModel.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(end_time, start_time))
```

According to this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579935/1757321), there's a way to get items from same day by using `CURDATE()`

Comment: in `def get_past_week(self):` are you sure you want to call your class `self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
end_time = datetime.now()
start_time = datetime(end_time.year,end_time.month,end_time.day)
```

That will set end_time to actual time, and start_time to the same day as end_time, but with the time at 0 hours and 0 seconds.

Comment: I think that's right. Thanks. Will mark this as answer soon. Trying other answers

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

end_time = datetime.now()
start_time = datetime.combine(end_time, datetime.min.time()) #Reset the hours/time offset
qs =  MyModel.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_time, end_time))
```

Or something even simpler:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(pub_date__startswith=end_time.date())
```

Comment: Your approach is awesome too. Thanks